# How to load an adjacency list in a Neo4j database?

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I have about 2.7 million rows of adjacency list type data:

```
CID | MID | CATGY
```

(CATGY depends on MID)

Thus, I want to make multiple edges between various different customers and merchants. But as I load using this query-

```
load csv with headers from 'file:/small_data.csv' as row
create (c:cust),(m:mer),(ct:cat)
set c.id = row.CID, m.id = row.MID, ct.name = row.CATGY
create (c)-[:buys_at]->(m), (c)-[:buys]->(ct),(m)-[:has_cat]->(ct)
```

it creates unique nodes for all the customers and vendors. So I get 2.7 million nodes of each type. But the actual customers and vendors are less than that.

How do I create unique nodes based on CID and MID and then match them together based on the records?

few example records-

```
1   a    FOOD
1   b    AUTO
2   a    FOOD
2   b    AUTO
```

Edit:

I tried running this query with a very small sample (25 rows), but it runs endlessly, taking up more and more memory until it saturates the RAM usage.

```
load csv with headers from 'file:/small_1.csv' as row
MERGE (c:cust {id: row.CID})
MERGE (m:mer {id: row.MID})
CREATE (c)-[:buys_at]->(m)
```

Comment: 1) Are you sure that you're not processing the entire csv file even if you're only acting on 100 rows? 2) Do you have indices for those labels and properties? 3) It is often better to do two passes: a first pass to create the nodes, a second pass to create the relationships. In the second pass use `MATCH` to get the nodes and `MERGE` or `CREATE` for the relationships.

Comment: 1) no, its a different csv that I created by hand. 2) The labels are just integers which I am using as IDs. What are indices and how can I use them?

Comment: An index or constraint is created for a label/property pair, like the `id` property for your `:cust` label. Without it your merge queries will fetch all nodes that have the label and test each one for the property/value, which gets expensive quickly. If the database is empty and you import 100 rows of csv, this is not the problem. If the database has data from before, this may be the problem. Read about indices and constraints here: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/graphdb-neo4j.html#graphdb-neo4j-schema

Comment: Mark Needham has several helpful blog posts about performance with load csv, for example http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/

Comment: but given my smaller sample size (less than 30 rows), how can it take so much memory and runtime?

Comment: Here, take a look a sample I am using -  http://pastebin.com/TrzcRQdQ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92483/discussion-between-jjaderberg-and-goelakash).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is `MERGE` instead of CREATE :

```
load csv with headers from 'file:/small_data.csv' as row
MERGE (c:cust {id: row.CID})
MERGE (m:mer {id: row.MID})
MERGE (ct:cat {name: row.CATGY})
MERGE (c)-[:buys]->(ct)
MERGE (m)-[:hast_cat]->(ct)
CREATE (c)-[:buys_at]->(m)
```

See the [documentation for MERGE](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html)

For performances matters, make sure you have enough RAM allocated.

Secondly make sure you have indexes or unique constraints on :

- cust / id
- mer / id
- cat / name

Thirdly, you can batch commit every 1000 lines :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
load csv with headers from 'file:/small_data.csv' as row
MERGE (c:cust {id: row.CID})
MERGE (m:mer {id: row.MID})
MERGE (ct:cat {name: row.CATGY})
MERGE (c)-[:buys]->(ct)
MERGE (m)-[:hast_cat]->(ct)
CREATE (c)-[:buys_at]->(m)
```

Comment: Throws error: 'c already declared (line 4, column 8 (offset: 142))'. I replaced the aliases in MERGE query (c -> a, m->b etc), but now the query runs forever.

Comment: ha sorry yes, I forgot to remove your part of the query, updated

Comment: But the running time is still very slow (Its been five minutes since its been running, guess I should stop it)

Comment: Depends your neo4j configuration. cache type, you have no periodic commit so it will try to commit all in one tx.

Comment: also do you have indexes ?

Comment: I just added them and then ran the query. Its still taking a lot of time.

Comment: what is the JVM memory allocated to neo4j ?

Comment: please also paste the result of the `:schema` command in the browser

Comment: Indexes
  ON :cat(name) ONLINE  
  ON :cust(id)  ONLINE  
  ON :mer(id)   ONLINE  

No constraints

Comment: I tried on a windows machine and this worked. Any idea how I can scale it to 20million rows? The server crashes. I have given 6GB to JVM (8GB physical RAM).

Comment: you'll better look at the import-tool instead or the batchInserter Java API

Answer (score 0):

You should make the nodes like merge (r:products{name:"fallout4"})

why use set? 
you could first create the unique nodes like

first you create your nodes
Food, auto... with a label

a,b with a label

1,2 with a label

and then you make your relations. create(a)-[]->(food)
or with merge
So they will point to same node if something has the same property